# Listview crashes when scroll down and click an item

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

The code says that clicking on cart image the name of product becomes red.This works for the first items that appears in `listview`(only items that you can see on phone display).

Scrolling down to see other items in `listview` it works but when i click on item to add it to cart the application crashes at line :
 `parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewNameChangeColor).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

with NullPointerException

I don't see what could cause the problem and some help it would be appriciated.Thanks.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listTransferObjectProduct.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listTransferObjectProduct.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return  position;
    }

    private class Holder {
        TextView textViewProduct;
        TextView textViewNameChangeColor;
        ImageView addOneItem;
        TextView textViewPrice;
    }

    Holder holder;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        product = listTransferObjectProduct.get(position);
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_product_adapter, null);

        holder.textViewProduct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        holder.textViewPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
        holder.textViewNameChangeColor =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameChangeColor);
        holder.textViewNameChangeColor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.addOneItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAdd);

        holder.textViewProduct.setText(product.articleName);
        holder.textViewNameChangeColor.setText(product.articleName);
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(Double.toString(listTransferObjectProduct.get(position).price) + " $");


        holder.addOneItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        utility.incrementCounter((Activity) context);
                        product = listTransferObjectProduct.get(position);
                        product.quantity = 1;
                        parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewNameChangeColor).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        utility.saveToSharedPrefereces(product, true);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewNameChangeColor).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: try to get view's object in `onTouch()` method  `v.getParent` object then do your process.